# Everything is Out of Order: Php - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I am trying to create a php script that gets values from a MySQL database, displays a header with the time_stamp that comes from an array, and a sub header with a value called "working_ra" with values underneath those categories. The values that go underneath both categories are being displayed in a table. I am sorting the values of the working_ra in the query so I can run a while loop saying that if they're not the same to display the next working_ra and continue echoing values. Here is my code:

```
foreach ($date as $i) {
    echo "<pre>"."<h2>".$i."</h2>"."</pre>";
    $result = mysqli_query ($con, "SELECT * FROM Signing WHERE value1 = 'Ings' AND time_stamp = '$i' ORDER BY working_ra");

    $num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    $desk = $row["working_ra"];

    echo "var_desk starting value ","<b>", $desk,"</b>";

    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>", $row["first"],"</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        if ((string)$desk != (string)$row["working_ra"]) {
            echo "</table>";

            $desk = $row["working_ra"];

            echo "var_desk next value ","<b>",$desk,"</b>";
            echo "<br />";
            echo "<table border='1'>";
        }

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>", $row["first"],"</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    $result->free();
}

$con->close();
```

Everything works fine until it hits to the second "desk" name. Then the tables that are supposed to be with the next value get shifted to the next date. Here is what it looks like on the page:

[image: php script output]

aSFashagh, Jeremy, Jeremy, and Johnny are all supposed to be under (Phil, January 10 2013) but is shifted down into the next date and working_ra (Phil, January 20 2013). zffaA, andsdfdsggsdhj are all supposed to be under (Phil,January 20 2013) but are under (Phil, February 25 2013) instead. Whats weird is that the method did work **WITHOUT** trying to put all of the values in tables.

My assumption is that it could be the ordering of which the table tags are ending and starting, but I have tried numerous amounts of things and still cannot figure out what is wrong.

**EDIT**

Sorry its very confusing to say. But im trying to get it to where everything is shifted up the way its supposed to be. Where the values of "first" belong with their corresponding time_stamp and working_ra. For instance, the value of Johnny in the MySQL db has a value of working_ra - Phil and a value of time_stamp - January 10, 2013. However as you can see, Johnny is not underneath (Phil, January 10 2013) instead January 20, 2013. Its not the query thats the problem, it has something to do with the while loop and the table and I just can't figure it out.

**The only two values that are correct are Zack and Why which have corresponding values of (working_ra = "Bob", time_stamp = "January 10, 2013")**

Comment: You're out of order. The whole freaking system is out of order. You want the truth? You want the truth?! You can't handle the truth!

Comment: We'll, you're looping and querying by date...

Comment: @bfavaretto I should be able to loop a query by date and then for each row that corresponds with that date, print out the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what the problem was. I needed to add a "/table" tag when the while loop breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is with the mysql row pointer.  You already used mysqli_fetch_array once before the while loop therefore shifting the current mysql row to the next row.

This code
`mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);`
will reset the pointer.

Place it right before your while loop.

Comment: I thought this might work but it still kept the same values shifted down one :/